# How can I get Azure to use an SSH key when doing a node.js deploy via git?

Tags: ssh, azure, git, continuous-integration

I'm deploying a node.js app to Azure Web Services using git from my local machine via: git push azure master

One of our npm packages is a private repo hosted on BitBucket. Without Azure having an SSH key to clone that repo, the deployment fails.

How can I add an SSH key to my Azure server that will get used during these deployment executions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup a deployment key on Bitbucket that you can provide to Azure to get the package from Bitbucket.

1. Take the full deploy URL (such as
   https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/deploy), and replace /deploy
   with /api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1. So it'll look like
   https://$mysite:BigRandomPassword@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1
2. Run curl on this URL, which returns an SSH public key. It's returned
       as a JSON string, so you'll need to remove the quotes. It should
       look like ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1etc...
3. Set this string as a 'deploy
       key' on your GitHub/Bitbucket/GitLab repository.

Full source [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment)